# using a Bash variable in place of a file as input for an executable

Tags: file, pipe, bash

I have an executable that is used in a way such as the following:

```
executable -v -i inputFile.txt -o outputFile.eps
```

In order to be more efficient, I want to use a Bash variable in place of the input file. So, I want to do something like the following:

```
executable -v -i ["${inputData}"] -o outputFile.eps
```

Here, the square brackets represent some clever code.

Do you know of some trick that would allow me to pipe information into the described executable in this way?

Many thanks for your assistance

Comment: It's a bit unclear just what you want to happen. Like, what is value of inputData?

Comment: "${inputData}" is simple, ASCII data which I want to 'package' as a file without actually using a file (which may need to be stored in non volatile memory). The user mikyra suggests an approach involving process substitution which I think is exactly I need. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Ah, now I got it... Cool, I didn't know of that. Apparently it is a *bash* feature, not supported by plain *sh* or *dash*, so better remember to use `#!/bin/bash` when using that in a script. +1+1

Answer (score 64, accepted):

You can use the following construct:

```
<(command)
```

So, to have bash create a FIFO with the command as the output for you, instead of your attempted `-i ["${inputData}"]`, you would do:

```
-i <(echo "$inputData")
```

Therefore, here is your final total command:

```
executable -v -i <(echo "$inputData") -o outputFile.eps
```

Comment: This process substitution is exactly what I need. Thank you very much for your assistance!

Comment: I encountered some command that need to seek the input file, where fifo pipe doesn't work. Zsh has a =() implemented as a temp file, which works well.

Comment: https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Process-Substitution worth to read this section

Comment: This fails if `inputData` contains literal backslashes, or is `-e`

Comment: For a solution that works in the cases that @Eric mentions, see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51022016/5353461).

Answer (score 20):

[Echo is not safe to use for arbitrary input](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/65819/280944).

To correctly handle pathological cases like `inputdata='\ntest'` or `inputdata='-e'`, you need

```
executable -v -i <(cat <<< "$inputData")
```

In `zsh`, the `cat` is not necessary

---

**Edit:** even this adds a trailing newline. To output the exact variable contents byte-by-byte, you need

```
executable -v -i <(printf "%s" "$inputData")
```

Answer (score 3):

**Note: zsh only:**

To get a filename containing the contents of `${variable}`, use:

```
<(<<<${variable})
```

Note:

- `<<<${variable}` redirects `STDIN` to come from `${variable}`
- `<<<${variable}` is equivalent to (but faster than) `cat <<<${variable}`

So for the OP's case:

```
executable -v -i <(<<<${inputData}) -o outputFile.eps
```

Comment: This also emits a trailing newline after the contents of `variable`, which in most cases doesn't matter, but might be worth drawing attention to

Answer (score 1):

I couldn't find a better solution than making temporary file and reference it into a variable.  For example:

```
key=$(mktemp);    # Creating a random file in the tmp folder
echo "some data" > $key;    # Filling the file with content
ssh -i $key user@localhost
```

I assume when the bash session is close, the variable and temporary file is cleared

Comment: Actually, `mktemp` is an external utility, so it's up to your program to clean up the file when it's done with it