# Grep unrecognized option '-->' while parsion content of html element

Tags: linux, grep, html-parsing

I'm trying to parse content of div element with class "error-icon" and grep shows unrecognized option with multiple attempts.Here is my code.Please help

```
#!/bin/sh

verifyCard=$1

if [ -z "${verifyCard}" ]; then echo "No argument supplied"; exit 1; fi

response=$(curl 'https://www.isic.org/verify/' -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:80.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/80.0' -H 'Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8' -H 'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5' --compressed -H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' -H 'Origin: https://www.isic.org' -H 'Connection: keep-alive' -H 'Referer: https://www.isic.org/verify/' -H 'Cookie: PHPSESSID=46plnh6b31e2pusv1do6thfbm7; AWSELB=AF73034F18B38D7DCED6DEDC728D31BA3F3A73F96747FEE7FA7C4F7A74BC9954E5928CBDDD5C053FFB2A37CE37136C4BA008B15163192B34CFA04D35BEC4ED0D0D2913A2FB; AWSELBCORS=AF73034F18B38D7DCED6DEDC728D31BA3F3A73F96747FEE7FA7C4F7A74BC9954E5928CBDDD5C053FFB2A37CE37136C4BA008B15163192B34CFA04D35BEC4ED0D0D2913A2FB; _ga=GA1.2.650910486.1600495658; _gid=GA1.2.731428038.1600495658; _gat=1' -H 'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1' --data-raw 'verify_card_number=${$verifyCard}')

output=$(grep -o '<div class="error-icon">[^<]*' "$response" | grep -o '[^>]*$')

echo "$output"
```

Comment: Please paste your script first at [shellcheck.net](http://www.shellcheck.net/) and try to implement the recommendations made there.

Comment: Posted on shellcheck.net and it didn't help.Thanks for interesting tip anyway.

Comment: [Don't Parse XML/HTML With Regex.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/3776858) I suggest to use an XML/HTML parser (xmlstarlet, xmllint ...).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The line

```
response=$(curl ...)
```

puts the output of the `curl` command in a variable named `response`.

In your `grep` command you try to pass the expansion of the variable as an argument.

```
output=$(grep -o '<div class="error-icon">[^<]*' "$response" | ...)
```

`grep` tries to interpret the value as command line arguments which may result in various errors depending on the actual output. In my test I got a message `grep: <some html code>: File name too long` because it tries to interpret this as a file name argument.

You should save the data in a file and pass this to `grep`. Adapt the name and location of the temporary file as necessary. Example:

```
#!/bin/sh

verifyCard=$1

if [ -z "${verifyCard}" ]; then echo "No argument supplied"; exit 1; fi

curl -o response-file 'https://www.isic.org/verify/' -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:80.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/80.0' -H 'Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8' -H 'Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5' --compressed -H 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' -H 'Origin: https://www.isic.org' -H 'Connection: keep-alive' -H 'Referer: https://www.isic.org/verify/' -H 'Cookie: PHPSESSID=46plnh6b31e2pusv1do6thfbm7; AWSELB=AF73034F18B38D7DCED6DEDC728D31BA3F3A73F96747FEE7FA7C4F7A74BC9954E5928CBDDD5C053FFB2A37CE37136C4BA008B15163192B34CFA04D35BEC4ED0D0D2913A2FB; AWSELBCORS=AF73034F18B38D7DCED6DEDC728D31BA3F3A73F96747FEE7FA7C4F7A74BC9954E5928CBDDD5C053FFB2A37CE37136C4BA008B15163192B34CFA04D35BEC4ED0D0D2913A2FB; _ga=GA1.2.650910486.1600495658; _gid=GA1.2.731428038.1600495658; _gat=1' -H 'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1' --data-raw 'verify_card_number=${$verifyCard}'

output=$(grep -o '<div class="error-icon">[^<]*' response-file | grep -o '[^>]*$')

rm response-file

echo "$output"
```

If you use `bash` or `zsh` instead of `sh`, there are ways to substitute some variable value as an input file, see e.g. the answers in [using a Bash variable in place of a file as input for an executable](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14840178/10622916).